# Is it safe to keep all databases on one SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, security, production-environment, multi-tenant

I'm creating a Multi-Tenant application that uses separate databases for each 'client'.

Is it safe to keep all the clients databases on one SQL server? Assuming I give each db its own user account?

Thanks

Comment: To clarify, I assume you are asking primarily from a security stand point as opposed to Availability/DR?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Security is in my top concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an excellent blog post by Brent Ozar last week on this exact subject.

[How To Design Multi-Client Databases](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/06/how-design-multiclient-databases/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats basically good idea to manage the tenanats from one sql server(better in terms of resources etc), but you need to create one seperate database for storing the connections strings of other tenant databases, roles etc.

It would be fine with one sql server, if you decide  later on to place all the data into cloud.  Basically its easy to manage . Also If you want to update any procedure, you can do it easily for all the tenants.

Comment: Better Resilience and robustness

Answer (score 0):

I'd normally use one database per client on the same instance.

From a security perspective, you then have only to deal with logins and users: not permissions per schema or whatever in one big database.

Note that SQL Server will balance resources across all database per instance fairly effectively: not all databases will be in use at the same time so memory etc will be allocated to need. You lose this advantage with multiple instances.